# Incorrect work of the method StringBufferInputStream.read in DalvikVM

Tags: android

```
byte[] buf=new byte[5];

StringBufferInputStream sbis=new StringBufferInputStream("5");
int c=-2;
c=sbis.read(buf, 0, 5);
c=sbis.read(buf, 1, 4);
```

As a result, c == 0 but it should be c == -1

I tried StringBufferInputStream of openjdk-6-src-b24-14_nov_2011 and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the SDK are you using? I've just run this on an emulator (ADT 17) and the result *is* -1.

You may already be aware, but StringBufferInputStream has been [depreciated](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html), and it is now recommended to used [StringReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/StringReader.html) instead

Comment: I am using ADT 16 (API 13). The same result is returned when running on a real device with version 4.0.3. Class StringBufferInputStream used in the existing code, of course in the new code, it should not be used.

Comment: ADT 17 (API Level 15) on a real device with version 4.0.3 return 0.